# Go from one page to another with urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, webautomation

I'm writing a program and I need to go from one page to another like you would on a computer.

On urllib I go to a page and get a url from that pages source then I take that url and I go to that but I'm getting an error from the site saying I came from the wrong page since urllib doesn't start on one page and go to another it opens a new page instead. 
.
here is some example code:

```
tree = self.opener.open('http://www.example.com').read()
#Beautiful soup parsing to get the new _url
new_page = self.opener.open('http://www.example/new_url.com').read()
print new_page #Output is error page
```

How can I write it so that the site thinks I came from the previous page I was on?

Thank You

Comment: Do you have to use `urllib2` - I have a feeling you'd find using `requests` and its `requests.session` object a lot easier to use. Otherwise, you may wish to try setting a referrer header and see if that makes the site happy.

Comment: i was thinking of using requests but can you add a header with requests  becuase it doesnt work without a header

Comment: It's as simple as `requests.get('http://example.com/page', headers={'Referer': 'http://example.com'})`

Comment: It seems [Mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) would fit in just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the site you are trying to access has these kind of sensibilities, you will be in a lot of trouble trying to get into it using "urllib2" only -as it just provides a very low level access to http - you 'd need to emulate in your program the HTTP headers saying where you came from, and also replay any cookies you might have got on the first access.

There are 3rd party Python modules that make these tasks much easier, and I'd suggestyou to sue the "[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)" library instead - or at least "[mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)". it is possible that not even using these, what you are asking is achieved by default - but follow the documentation an dexamples of the project you choose and it should be much simpler.

Comment: I did it by doing
`self.opener.addheaders = [('Referer','http://www.example.com')]`